# Java- Print individual words from a sequence of characters

Tags: java, string, arraylist, data-structures

The method I wrote should return a list of the individual words in the tweet. A word is defined as the characters in the range [a, z] or [A, Z]. For example, the sentence "I hate my job" should print:
I
hate
my
job

This is my current implementation. I also included the private member variables needed for this method:

```
public ArrayList<String> getWords() {
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList();
    String st = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < content.length(); ++i) {
      char s = content.charAt(i);

      if(s == ' ' && st.equals("") == false) {
        words.add(st);
        st = ("");
      }
       if(s >= 'a' && s <= 'z' || s >= 'A' && s <= 'Z') {
        st += s;
      }
    }

    return words;
  }


  private String content;
```

This is my current output for the input "i hate my job":

```
  i
  hate
  my
```

Expected output:
i
hate
my
job

This is my current output for the input "i love my job #winning":

```
 i

 love

 my

 job
```

Expected output:

i

love

my

job

winning

Why is my output not correct? I don't see why it wouldn't print the last words?

Comment: How did you expect the `#winning` become `winning`? And why not split the string based on a space?

Comment: There's no space (' ') after the final word, so your `if` does not get invoked which means the word isn't added to `words`.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a better way to do this by using the `split` method for a String. You could do something like this :

```
public static List<String> getWords() {
    return Arrays.asList(content.split(" "));
}
```

Then if you want to delete the # of the Tweet simply use the `replace` method like this :

```
public static List<String> getWords() {
    return Arrays.asList((content.replace("#","")).split(" "));
}
```

Comment: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<String> to ArrayList<String>` and `Cannot invoke replace(String, String) on the array type String[]`

Comment: Thank you, you're right! I fixed it. The first error was because the `Arrays.asList` returns a `List<>` and not an `ArrayList<>` I think, this should be fixed only by changing the expected function return. The second one was because the `.replace()` was made after the `.split()`!

Answer (score 0):

- Simple fix: add the `st` to the list *after* the main loop.
- Additional fixes: use standard methods such as `String.isEmpty` and `Character.isLetter`
- Use `StringBuilder` instead of string to accumulate each word (then `st.length() > 0` should be used).

```java
public ArrayList<String> getWords() {
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < content.length(); ++i) {
        char c = content.charAt(i);

        if (Character.isWhitespace(c) && st.length() > 0) {
            words.add(st.toString());
            st.setLength(0); // clear string builder
        }

        if(Character.isLetter(c)) {
            st.append(c);
        }
    }
    if (st.length() > 0) {
        words.add(st.toString());
    }

    return words;
}
```

---

However, it may be better to use method [`String::split`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)), get the array of strings and convert it into list, using an interface `List` instead of specific implementation:

```java
public List<String> getWords() {
    return Arrays.asList(content.split("[^a-zA-Z]+"));
}
```

Here regular expression `"[^a-zA-Z]+"` means that the word delimiters are any non-English letter characters (quantifier `+` means at least 1 character).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how your code can be fixed. It is not adding the last word, because the second if condition below never gets satisfied. If you add a space at the end of the input string, it will show up as you expected.

```java
public static ArrayList<String> getWordss(String content) {
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList();
        String st = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < content.length(); i++) {
            char s = content.charAt(i);
            if (i == content.length()  - 1) {
                st += s;
                words.add(st);
            }
            if(s == ' ' && !st.equals("")) {
                words.add(st);
                st = ("");
            }

            if(s >= 'a' && s <= 'z' || s >= 'A' && s <= 'Z') {
                st += s;
            }
        }
```

Here is a simpler version of what you are trying to do.

```java
    public static List<String> getWords(String content) {
        return Arrays
                .stream(content.split(" "))
                .filter(f -> f.matches("^[a-zA-Z]+"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Comment: 1. The first method is missing return statement and closing `}` 2. The first method does not check the last character in the sentence to be a letter so any character is appended to the last word. 3. The _simpler_ version discards any word starting with a hash `#` which may be critical for parsing Twitter postings.

Answer (score 0):

You are skipping to add the last element in the loop. Could below would solve the problems:

```
public ArrayList<String> getWords() {
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList();
        String st = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < content.length(); ++i) {
            char s = content.charAt(i);

            if(s == ' ' && !st.equals("")) {
                words.add(st);
                st = ("");
            }
            if(s >= 'a' && s <= 'z' || s >= 'A' && s <= 'Z') {
                st += s;
            }

            // This help to add last element in the list
            if (i == content.length()-1){
                words.add(st);
            }
        }

        return words;
    }
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Here is the all code.

```
public class SGCtest {

    private String content;

    public ArrayList<String> getWords() {
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList();
        String st = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < content.length(); ++i) {
            char s = content.charAt(i);

            if(s == ' ' && !st.equals("")) {
                words.add(st);
                st = ("");
            }
            if(s >= 'a' && s <= 'z' || s >= 'A' && s <= 'Z') {
                st += s;
            }

            // This help to add last element in the list
            if (i == content.length()-1){
                words.add(st);
            }
        }

        return words;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SGCtest a = new SGCtest();
        a.content="i love my job #winning";
        System.out.println(" Printing the input string: "+a.content);
        ArrayList <String> bb =a.getWords();
        System.out.println(" Printing List: "+bb);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line of code removes all non-letters in a string and return the list of words:

```
    List words = Arrays.asList(content.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\\s]", "").split("\\s+"));
```

First, the `replaceAll` method removes all characters that are not letters or spaces in the string. Then, the `split` method splits the string by the spaces to place all the words in an array, which is further converted to a List by the method `asList`.